# Why is calling this function crashing when it is called more than once?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am bit puzzled by this code and I am trying to understand why it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string print_array_string(std::vector<std::string> ar) 
{ 
   std::cout << "Vector size:" << ar.size() << " values:";
   for(auto &i: ar) {
       std::cout << i << "; ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {

   std::vector <std::string> ar {"ab", "cd", "ef"};

   print_array_string(ar);    
   print_array_string(ar);    

   return 0;
}
```

When this code runs I get:

```
Array size:3 values:ab; cd; ef; 
*** Error in `/tmp/test': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006040d8 ***
======= Backtrace: ========= 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f8f7898c725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f8f78994f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f8f78998abc]
/tmp/test[0x40115d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f8f78935830]
/tmp/test[0x400df9]
...
```

I am not understanding what the impact of the call is doing.
Would anybody enlighten me?

thank you,

-daniel

Comment: The function is supposed to return `string` but does not return anything, Undefined behavior.

Comment: Ha. thanks. Such a silly error.

Comment: @AlexD That should be posted as an Answer, no?

Comment: Uhh, why does that even compile?

Comment: @KeithM Oh, it is a minor thing, really. Does not deserve to become an answer. But thanks anyway :)!

Comment: My impression was that if it solves or helps solve OP's problem, it can/should be posted as an Answer. If people think it was trivial to solve they could just not upvote it or something.

Comment: Always compile with warnings enabled. :)

Comment: **TL;DR;** Dangling stuff leftover from 1st call.

Comment: just a little hint: replace "array" with "vector" because a vector is not an array.  If you are going for bigger projects it's better you are precise.

Comment: @tistCoder OTOH it could be helpful for some applications to have the same function name overloaded for both `std::vector<std::string>&` and `std::string*`.

Comment: @dmg Speaking of which, you should change `std::vector<std::string> ar` to `std::vector<std::string> &ar`. Otherwise it will create a copy of the entire vector each time you call this function to print. Even better, change it to `const std::vector<std::string> &ar` if you intend on not editing it inside that function to double-check that you're not editing it on accident (more helpful for longer functions).

Comment: @Keith M It could be but I wouldn't recommend the same name for 2 different things. I'd go for print_container_string / print_string_container. Both of them are containers but their core is different. PS: That's my opinion

Comment: @tistCoder Overloaded functions can reduce maintenance costs in the event of a variable type change, though... so I like them. PS: That's my opinion ;D

Comment: @Keith M I guess you didn't read my whole comment, didn't you? It meant that if someone wants to overload a function/method then that one should use a name which tells other programmers what it does. E.g: print_array_string can print string-arrays, vectors, lists... then I would rather give it the name print_container_string because it can print more than just an array. I didn't say he has to make 3 functions like print_array_string, print_vector_string...

Comment: Thank you all. I think the big message here is to always compile with all warnings enabled. One thing that was interesting about this function is that, when I made it generic (using template) it worked for vectors of integers, but it failed for vectors of strings. Also, it was a heisenbug: it failed in some cases and not in others. For example, it would fail in the first instance if the vector of string was empty.

Comment: @tistCoder I did read your whole comment; I just misunderstood, apparently. Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by AlexD in the comments:

> The function is supposed to return `string` but does not return
>   anything, Undefined behavior.

(This answer was added as per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)